# MVC Validation message styles not applying

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have been working on modal validations using data annotations. My issue is when I am displaying validation message from modal then styles are not applying, when I debug code using chrome developer tools I see markup language as follows

```
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" 
    data-valmsg-for="StudentName" 
    data-valmsg-replace="true">
    <span for="StudentName" class>student name is required</span></span>
```

But when the validation message is custom message defined in razor view then styles are applying and markup language is as follows

```
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" 
    data-valmsg-for="StudentName" 
    data-valmsg-replace="true">student name is required</span>
```

Can anyone please help on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: put your styles on the outer span - the one with the inner span won't be able to be made using data annotations, it just uses a single span and adds field-validation-error class when it errors

Comment: Thanks pete,but actually this markup is not written by me it was generated from html.validationmessagefor () control i got it by opening chrome debug options in both cases

Comment: Weird, never seen it create a double span before! Anyway you need to show the styles that are not being applied

Comment: Styles i havent applied any thing other than text-danger in validationmessagefor and one more thing to add this is partial view loaded using jquery ajax call.

Comment: To clarify the issue, you have something similar to @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attribute, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) in razor and the text-danger styles aren't being applied to the error message?

Comment: Yes @jeffbricco

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: It was against to my company policy even this markup code is similar to the original one,i have changed modal properties

Answer (score 1):

View Code:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "CustomeError" })

Style Code:

<style>
    .CustomeError {
        color: chocolate;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @ramadoss i have already tried this custom style is applying to parent span but valudation message is in child span for which nothing is applying

Comment: Please improve this answer by adding an explaination about why this code solves the problem.